# Sudden increase or decrease in time series

Tags: variance, pattern-recognition

There is a call center which records the number of complaints against a service on daily basis.

For example, the values below show the number of complaints for the last 6 months of a service:

> Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun
>   020, 030, 010, 030, 045, 065

**Question:** How one can find `sudden increase/decrease` in number of complaints for a service over a period of time OR `sudden increase/decrease` in number of accidents/births/tourists/students/etc in last 6 months?

sudden increase/decrease should be adjustable for `sudden` and `increase/decrease`.

I need help and suggestions to figure out possible solutions.

**Edit # 1**

This approach has to be automated. A computer program will analyze a certain window of historic data and will identify sudden increase or decrease. So basically there are two problems:

1. A modal to identify sudden change
2. Quantification of the modal

Time plot or Linear Graph can be used to plot the changes. But I don't know how to quantify this plot/graph. Any suggestion in this area will be helpful.

**Edit # 2**

I received following advice from someone. Hope it help

> Take your deltas: 10, -20, 20, 15, 20 and find the mean and std dev of
>   their absolute values.  The numbers outside of say two standard
>   deviations that are big numbers show you sudden increase/decrease. 
>   The small ones outside of two standard deviations show unusual
>   stability. The rest are just your normal slow drift.  I only see slow
>   drifting in these numbers.

**Edit # 3**
As shown in this picture, the red line is a normal condition for last 6 months while blue line indicates a sudden increase in last 4 months of 6 month window.
[image]

**Edit # 4**
Instead of rephrasing this whole question, i have posted a new question as [How to quantify increasing nature of dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303835/how-to-quantify-increasing-nature-of-dataset). I will delete this question.

Comment: Is your objective to forecast complaints or simply identify whether there has been a significant increase in complaints? Either way, a time plot would help.

Comment: @Digio Just to identify from historic data within certain time period

Comment: @Digio I don't know how to quantify the time plot.

Comment: You already have your quantity, it's the number of complaints on a daily or monthly basis. The time plot consists of plotting complaints vs points in time. Depending on the size of your historical data and the degree of autocorrelation, you've got many options to detect significant change over time. It could range from a linear model, to a GLM (such as Poisson regression), to a time series model.

Comment: This question is similar, you may be able to use the answers https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267060/what-is-the-best-statistics-way-to-identify-the-gap-of-a-plot

Comment: @Hugh I am unable to map given solutions with my problem. Change Point Analysis is to identify changes in the series but these changes are not going to indicate something `sudden`, Linear Regression is about prediction next values. More help is required.

Comment: can't you just compute the usual mean and variance and decide arbitrarily that 2 or 3 sigmas away from the mean is a splike?

Comment: You have to define "sudden" in a precise way that matches what you need. Then you can develop an algorithm..

Comment: @edouard would you please explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

A [control chart](http://asq.org/learn-about-quality/data-collection-analysis-tools/overview/control-chart.html) is a helpful way to visualize the performance of the call center over time. It's good you applied edits to specify this is a problem of *forecasting* rather than inference, or prediction: forecasting relies on projecting forward in time, whereas prediction may borrow information from the future or the present to infer what trends may be.

[Queuing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) often uses such models to forecast volumes to a call center. In queuing theory, you make some assumptions about the nature of the calls: namely that they arrive with independent interarrival times at a time-varying rate. Probabilistically, this leads to distributions over time intervals which are Poisson. Detecting changes in Poisson rates from one time interval to the next makes use of a [Markov Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). which utilizes several lagged states. As you allude to, 20 people calling within a one minute time frame may be a "peak", and may be a coincidence (or noise) in the signal, but if this rate is sustained for a number of "states" (intervals of time), you may eventually classify the state as a "peak time".

In order to conduct this type of analysis a number of definitions must additionally be laid out: you must define what comprises a "peak time": if the control chart reveals that such times are visually compelling, then the choice of cut off may be arbitrary, since normal volume may be (say) 3 calls per minute and high volume would comprise 30 calls per minute, making cut-offs between 5 and 20 essentially the same. You must also decide upon what is the appropriate interval of time: if you choose too large a time frame (say one hour), the latency of your detection may be too delayed to be useful. If you choose too short a time frame, the Poisson estimates of caller rates may be unreliable. You must also determine how many lagged states you would like to consider before you conclude decisively that the process has landed in a "high volume" state. So with intervals of 1 minute, but a 3 minute evaluation period, you would use a Markov chain with 3 lagged states considering 3 consecutive periods of "high" volume evidence that you are now in a high call volume state.

Roughly, this process is a poor man's filtering. There are more sophisticated filtering processes that can be applied, such as Kalman's filter, Bayesian particle filter, and so on.

Comment: This is not a forecasting problem, if the changed title is making it look like so then it is my mistake.

Comment: I have to have some quantitative value to decide whether there is a `sudden change` as compare to `normal condition`. Every service/product would have its own `normal condition`, for example normal condition for service A is 15 calls per day while 15 calls per day is a sudden change for service B. Sorry for bad explanation, i am not a statistician at all.

Comment: one more thing, once a `sudden change` has been identified, it may become `normal condition` based on the history of the service. For example if i want to know the change in last 6 months then 15 calls per day may be the sudden change but when i am looking for last 2 years then it is normal.