# How to quantify increasing nature of dataset

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

There is a call center which records the number of complaints against a service on daily basis.

For example, the values below show the number of complaints in a month

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30

05,06,07,05,05,04,05,04,07,08,07,08,06,07,07,06,08,08,09,11,12,11,07,13,13,15,16,18,19,21
```

[image]

I am not trying to estimate anything here. By looking at the graph i can see that the overall values are increasing from right to left. I don't know much statistics other than mean, median, mode so i phrased it as "increasing nature". I want a single numeric value (e.g. standard deviation) which would let me know if it is a straight horizontal line or going downwards or going upwards from left to right.

For example, suppose there is a function XYZ (which i am looking for) which receives this dataset and returns a numeric value from 0 to 100. 0 means the highly decreasing nature, 50 means straight line and 100 means highly increasing nature. If the graph is increasing and decreasing symmetrically across a horizontal line then the result would be 50 (as an average of increasing and decreasing natures). If the graph has more increasing nature then decreasing then the result would be > 50 and vice versa. Following are some sample graphs

[image] 
[image]

**Question:** How can I quantify increasing nature of this given data?

Comment: "quantify it's increasing nature" is incredibly vague. What do you mean by that? Are you trying to answer "is this increasing or could it just be ephemeral noise?" or are you trying to estimate the overall rate at which it's increasing or decreasing? or are you trying to get a smooth trend?  Or are you trying to model it more generally (so you can answer questions like "is it higher on Mondays?)?

Comment: @Glen_b I am not trying to estimate. If you look at the graph the overall values are increasing from start to end. I don't know much statistics other than mean, median, mode so i phrased it as "increasing nature". I want a single numeric value (e.g. standard deviation) which would let me know if it is a horizontal line or increasing from left to right. You are most welcome to edit the question and phrase it correctly or tell me how should i phrase it

Comment: It looks like you really do want to estimate a trend.  You could do this with linear regression, estimating its slope and testing that it is statistically greater than 0.  To my eye it looks like it has curvature and so you could fit the regression as a quadratic function of months and test the significance of the linear and quadrartic terms.

Comment: "which would let me know if it is a horizontal line or increasing from left to right" ... but you *already* stated it "was increasing from start to end"... it's not clear what more than that you need -- if you can see that, why would a number make a difference? What about the possibility that (a different set of data) is neither increasing from left to right nor a horizontal line; perhaps it decreases a bit then increases for example - what should it tell you then? Some additional clarity on the kind of information you seek would help. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... You don't need to know statistics (indeed it would be preferable if you avoided trying to couch anything in statistical terms) -- just describe in plain English the question(s) you're trying to answer.

Comment: @Glen_b an increasing and decreasing graph of a month will tell me it is "normal". let me edit the question with plain english

Comment: @Glen_b let's say you have multiple datasets incoming and you don't want to manually plot each dataset, find whether increasing/decreasing/no trend and report the same. In such cases, you would look for some notion of trend to be able to achieve the goal with a piece of code. I think the question makes perfect sense.

Comment: I can see how you're assigning 50 to the pure-cyclical one but I can't discern what exactly it is that you're focused on more generally there. For example based on your last comment -- but before I looked at your plots I wondered if a monotonic measure like a Mann-Kendall correlation (essentially a Kendall tau of y(t) vs t) might do -- it gives values between -1 and 1 but they could be rescaled if need be to match your 0 to 100. However that would rate the first, third and fourth plot all the same (as perfectly related). So while that kind of measure sort of works it doesn't pick ... ctd

Comment: ctd up the distinction you're making between those three, and I am not sure quite what the basis is for whatever your assessment of "ïncreasing nature" is there

Comment: @Glen_b I am just trying to figure out that no. of complaints in a month suddenly increased as compare to last month. Here "suddenly" is important because if increase is slow or low then it won't be reported but if the increase is "sudden" only then it will be reported. The "sudden" will be defined by the management, but what it would be i don't know yet that is why i am looking for a sharp upward curve in the graph.

Comment: That's a bit more useful.